# ORM Code first - fix during design

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I run into a little trouble understanding object relational mapping in MVC4 simple web application in which there are users and their posted comments.
One user must have a lot of comments. So I added in my `UsersContext` class `public DbSet<UserWork> UserComments { get; set; }`

```
public class UsersContext : DbContext
{
    public UsersContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserWork> UserComments { get; set; }
}

[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public int? UserComId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserComId")]
    public virtual UserComment UserComLog { get; set; }        
}
public class UserComment 
{
    [Key]
    public int UserComId{ get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }        
    public string Comments{ get; set; }
    public DateTime postDate{get;set}
}
```

I am now stuck at realizing how all comments posted daily are stored such that I later can make a query like e.g `SELECT * FROM UserComment Inner join UserProfile ON UserComment.UserId=UserProfile.UserId WHERE postDate BETWEEN (...) AND (...)`

Comment: Is this model generated, or did you create the classes? Are you using EF Code First? Normally you would have property `public virtual ICollection<UserComment> UserComments` on your `UserProfile`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using Code First Migrations.

Seems like you need to edit your `UserProfile` class a little bit to allow for a user to have multiple comments. You need to make `UserComLog` a collection. Like:

```
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserComment> UserComLog { get; set; }        
}
```

With that, you'll have a user with multiple comments. Then, with the `UsersContext` you can access the database tables that Entity Framework have created for you. You just need to use your data context to write a Linq statement to access the data.

```
var context = new UsersContext();
var comments = context.UserComments.Where(d => d.postDate > new DateTime(2013,3,12) && d.postDate < new DateTime(2013,2,12) && d.UserId == userId);
```

`comments` would be a `IQueryable<UserComment>` which you can then pass into a loop to display on a page, or filter further if you wish.